# Building admin panel in expressjs, best way to count users without querying a lot?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, express

So I'm building an admin panel for my app. On the homepage of admin, I want to show some statistics about the usage.

Examples: signups in 24 hours, 7 days, 30 days, all time
signup method: user/pass, facebook, twitter etc

Now in my `admin.index` router, I'm doing async calls to my db (mongodb using mongoose) to get all the counts, and in the final callback function, rendering the page.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    async.parallel({ 
            // https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel
            // counts number of users in date ranges
            all_time: function(next) {
                console.log('querying');
                User.count({}, function (err, count) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    next(null, count);
                });
            },
            past_day: function(next) {
                console.log('querying');
                User.count({'created_at': {$gte: yesterday}}, function(err, count) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    next(null, count);
                });
            },
            week: function(next) {
                console.log('querying');
                User.count({'created_at': {$gte: week}}, function(err, count) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    next(null, count);
                });
            },
            month: function(next) {
                console.log('querying');
                User.count({'created_at': {$gte: month}}, function(err, count) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    next(null, count);
                });
            },
            // Counts number of user signups for each strategy
            local: function(next) {
                console.log('querying');
                User.count({'strategy': 'local'}, function(err, count) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    next(null, count);
                });
            },
            google: function(next) {
                console.log('querying');
                User.count({'strategy': 'google'}, function(err, count) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    next(null, count);
                });
            },
            facebook: function(next) {
                console.log('querying');
                User.count({'strategy': 'facebook'}, function(err, count) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    next(null, count);
                });
            },
            twitter: function(next) {
                console.log('querying');
                User.count({'strategy': 'twitter'}, function(err, count) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    next(null, count);
                });
            }
        }, 
        function(err, r) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('admin/index', {
                appName: Constants.APP_NAME, 
                title: 'Admin',
                total_users: r.all_time,
                yesterday: r.past_day,
                week: r.week,
                month: r.month,
                local: r.local,
                google: r.google,
                facebook: r.facebook,
                twitter: r.twitter
            })
        }
    );
}
```

But as it is right now, I am doing the computation (8 queries) on every page load. What's a better way to do it? I have never built CRUD applications, so do not know much. I have no experience with express and node, too so don't know much how it would work here.

Should I use memcached, or is it an overkill? How would that work with async?

Comment: I would pull all the data and sort/arrange using javascript

Comment: Too much memory usage could severely affect the speed. Plus doing this asynchronously would mean that I print out the results before I compute them.

Comment: anyone has any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is good to optimize when you can, take a look at the [$or operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).
Maybe you will can just use one request, depend on your data structure.
If you can't, you can make a document with only the counts, querying this doc and you get all counts in a small request.

But I think this optimization here isn't necessary. These queries are for administrators. Imagine you've 1 administrator and 10 000 users connected into your website, these query aren't for users, only for you, that you use sometimes; the impact is trivial.

Furthermore, your queries benefit from the fact that there are asynchrone, so your app can respond other users during the same time.

Comment: AFAIK, `$or` will do a cumulative request. So `$or: {foo: 1, bar: 2}` will find all things with foo=1 and bar=2. I want separate counts. Even if the impact isn't too much, is it worth it make so many queries every time?

Comment: `$or` with a `count` yes, it's useless. But my theorical idea is: with a `find` you can get all documents that you need to count, retrieving only fields you need (projection). And you make your own counting. But I think you have to use map/reduce to do that... Impact? that's rather that in most case you happen to need an optimization for **users**, not for the administrators (depends your app!). If you want separate counts, you will need to write it.. and again.. an impact, but now for **users**! (I suppose). For me, it really depends on how many time these queries will be executed.