# Writing express.js app. Where do helper methods go?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have started with express.js - my first JS web dev framework. I didn't make anything small, but started a bigger project. I'm learning, and building at the same time.

Coming from a Python/Flask background, express seems very complicated.

Like in python, if I want a helper method, I can just put it on top of the file, or in a new module, and import it. Super easy. But in node/express, things are async, and everything is in `exports` or `module.exports` (??). Where do helper methods go? How do I call them with callbacks?

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914334/building-admin-panel-in-expressjs-best-way-to-count-users-without-querying-a-lo) I asked, I was doing the same kind of computation multiple times. In Python, I would write a method (with if statements and parameters), and call it multiple times, using a `for.. in...` loop. The code I have right now is very redundant.

How do I do it in express? What are best practices for writing express code?

Comment: Perhaps share some of the code that you're doing that feels redundant and we can make concrete suggestions?  @Krasimir and hgoebl have good answers, but they could be more specific to your needs with some specific example on your end.

Comment: I did link to [a thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914334/building-admin-panel-in-expressjs-best-way-to-count-users-without-querying-a-lo) as an example.

Answer (score 13):

It really depends of what your helper is doing. If it operates with data which is passed as a parameter to it then you may save it in an external module and use `require` to access it.

```
// helpers/FormatString.js
module.exports = function(str) {
   return str.toUpperCase();
}

// app.js
var formatter = require("./helpers/FormatString");
```

However, if you need to modify the `request` or the `response` object then I'll suggest to define it as a middleware. I.e.:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   // ... do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

@Krasimir gave a correct answer. Regarding your question how to deal with asynchronous helper functions I can give you an example (not the usual foo/bar, but one of my own helper functions):

```
var cached; // as modules can act like singletons I can share values here

module.exports = function fetchGoogleCerts(options, callback) { // <-- callback
    var now = Date.now();
    if (ttl > now && cached) {
        callback(null, cached); // <-- return with success
        return;
    }

    request({
            uri: options.certsUrl || defaultCertsUrl,
            strictSSL: true
        }, function (err, response, body) {
            var error, certs;

            if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
                certs = jsonParse(body); // a local function
                if (!certs) {
                    callback('parse_error', null); // <-- return an error
                    return;
                }
                cached = certs;

                // ... more code

                callback(null, cached); // <-- success case
            } else {
                error = {
                    error: err,
                    statusCode: response.statusCode
                };
                log.error(error, 'error fetching google certs');
                callback(error); // <-- return an error
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And using the helper:

```
fetchGoogleCerts = require('./google-certs.js'),


module.exports = function fetchCertsAndDecodeIdToken(token, options, callback) {
    fetchGoogleCerts(options, function (err, googleCerts) {
        if (err) {
            callback({
                errorCode: codes.io_error,
                errorMsg: 'Unable to fetch Google certificates',
                error: err
            });
            return;
        }
        decodeAndVerifyGoogleIdToken(googleCerts, token, options, callback);
    });
};
```

As you can see above, the simple solution is to provide a **callback** function to your asynchronous helper function.

Of course you can also export an Object which extends `EventEmitter`, then you might not need a callback function, but register for the events. Here is an [Example for a helper which emits events](https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-usage/blob/master/lib/ReadStreamLineEmitter.js).